# Php login form is not working with pdo connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //DB configuration Constants
    define('_HOST_NAME_', 'localhost');
    define('_USER_NAME_', 'root');
    define('_DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('_DATABASE_NAME_', 'myblog');

    //PDO Database Connection
    try {
        $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='._HOST_NAME_.';dbname='._DATABASE_NAME_, _USER_NAME_, _DB_PASSWORD);
        $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $errMsg = '';
        //username and password sent from Form
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if($username == '')
            $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';

        if($password == '')
            $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';


        if($errMsg == ''){
            $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM  tbl_users WHERE username = :username');
            $records->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $records->execute();
            $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['password'])){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
                header('location:dashboard.php');
                exit;
            }else{
                $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
            }
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login Page PHP Script</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    label
    {
        font-weight:bold;
        width:100px;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    .box
    {
        border:1px solid #006D9C;
        margin-left:10px;
        width:60%;
    }
    .submit{
        border:1px solid #006D9C;
        background-color:#006D9C;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        float:right;
        padding:2px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <div align="center">
        <div class="tLink"><strong>Tutorial Link:</strong> <a href="http://www.stepblogging.com/get-alexa-rank-using-php/">Click Here</a></div><br />
        <div class="tLink"><strong>Demo Login Detail:</strong> demo / demo </div><br />
        <div style="width:300px; border: solid 1px #006D9C; " align="left">
            <?php
                if(isset($errMsg)){
                    echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">'.$errMsg.'</div>';
                }
            ?>
            <div style="background-color:#006D9C; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>
            <div style="margin:30px">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <label>Username  :</label><input type="text" name="username" class="box"/><br /><br />
                    <label>Password  :</label><input type="password" name="password" class="box" /><br/><br />
                    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" class='submit'/><br />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is logout.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("location:index.php");
    exit;
?>
```

and finally dashboard.php:

```
?php
    session_start();
    echo 'Welcome '.$_SESSION['username'];
?>
<br /><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
```

when i entered input details and submit.. it shows username and password is not found.

I created database and insert sql query is fine..

May i know, what my mistake?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked whether the `count($results) > 0` or the `password_verify($password, $results['password'])` condition isn't fulfilled? Which one is it?

Comment: may i know, how can i check? thanks..

Comment: Maybe try removing one of the conditions...if it works then the removed condition is problematic.

Comment: A php debugger would be helpful for that - see https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html But for now you could try `$errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
$errMsg .= count($results)>0 ? 'y':'n';
$errMsg .= password_verify($password, $results['password']) ? 'Y':'N';` - but don't forget to remove the extra code when you're done "debugging".

Comment: after following your comments, it shows same error.."Username and Password are not found
yN" ..

Comment: Then `password_verify(...)` returned false and this might or might not have to do anything with pdo.

Comment: so .. what is the solution for this one sir?.. thanks

Comment: I don't know; not enough information to solve this one. Maybe you did something wrong on the input-side (i.e. the script using password_hash() and INSERT/UPDATE to store the password). Maybe the definition of the database table field is wrong (too short e.g.). Maybe ...

Comment: nope sir.. i put all my source code.,, I can't justify, where is the mistak..

Comment: C'mon, you checked all those points in this short amount of time? Unlikely. You need to investigate it, think it over, check it step by step, refer to the manual. There's nothing to "justify"; just a problem to work on.... do it.

Comment: Your mistake appears to be that you are using `password_verify` but there is no `hash`. See my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">` I think you miss this

Answer (score 0):

In this line `if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['password'])){` you are using `password_verify`

I see two things.

First - Where is your hash?
Second - The line itself is incorrect.

It should be... `if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $hash)){`

BUT... prior to using this you have to get the hash for that record. Most likely stored in a hash table when the user was created. And define the variable like this... `$hash = $row['hash']`

If you are not hashing your passwords, change your sql statement to `'SELECT id,username,password FROM  admin WHERE username=:username AND password=:password'`. Then create another parameter binding for password.

**NOTE:** proper binding should be done like the following:

```
$records->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); // for integers
$records->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR); // for strings and dates
```

also it's good practice to use `$totalRows = $records->rowCount();` directly underneath `$results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to get your row count. Instead of `if(count($results) && ...` it would be `if($totalRows > 0 && ...` This way you have defined a variable that can always be used elsewhere on the page if need be.

**References**

[password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)